# Создание файла на джава

Tags: java

Как создать правильно файл который запускал би код написаний в IntelIdea на джава, потому что при открытие файла вискакивает ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

**учись гуглить , это пожалуй самый главный навык, которым нужно овладеть**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22381202/a-jni-error-has-occurred-please-check-your-installation-and-try-again-in-eclips

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: в текущем же виде стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: @aleksandr barakin... вот прочитай его вопрос.... **Как создать правильно файл который запускал би код написаний в IntelIdea на джава, потому что при открытие файла вискакивает ошибка** какой файл создать??? какое расширение у файла, которое он пытается открыть, IDE уже запущено или нет, и тд и тп. одни вопросы. с такой постановкой, ему вообще никто не ответит

Comment: даже очень плохо сформулированный вопрос можно «спасти» хорошим развёрнутым ответом. комментарий, состоящий из ссылки, и опублкованный вместо ответа, на хороший развёрнутый ответ ну никак не тянет. посмотрите на примеры хороших ответов, пожалуйста: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa